# Inflater and loop not working as it should

Tags: java, android, eclipse, loops

I am having a problem with a custom view I am currently doing for an app on android, I know there are many questions related with inflaters, but I cannot get around this problem.

the inflater i working just fine, but it should be doing the loop 3 times and is only doing it 1 so I only get one view on my final layout.

the relevant part of the code is this one

```
 void populate(String strcline, String url){
lLfD = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lLfD);

    try{

    JSONArray a1 = new JSONArray(strcline);

    for(int i = 0; i < a1.length(); i++){

        JSONArray a2 =  a1.getJSONArray(i);

        final String fUserId = a2.getString(0);
        String userName = a2.getString(1);
        String userPicture = url + a2.getString(2);


        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cellevery, lLfD);
        ImageView avatar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cellAvatar);
        downloadFile(userPicture, avatar);
        TextView cellName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cellName);
        cellName.setText(userName);


        lLfD.addView(child);

    }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    pDialog.dismiss();
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You look like you need to run findViewById only on the inflated view, otherwise it will just find the first one which is only the first one in your loop:

```
   View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cellevery, lLfD);
    ImageView avatar = (ImageView)child.findViewById(R.id.cellAvatar);
    downloadFile(userPicture, avatar);
    TextView cellName = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.cellName);
    cellName.setText(userName);
```

Here's an explanation of findViewById in your loop:

```
Loop 1:
1LfD->child1->R.id.cellAvatar (findViewById(R.id.cellAvatar) finds this one)

Loop 2:

1Lfd->
   child1->R.id.cellAvatar
   child2->R.id.cellAvatar (findViewById(R.id.cellAvatar) finds the child1.cellAvatar again)

Loop 3:
1LfD->
   child1->R.id.cellAvatar 
   child2->R.id.cellAvatar 
   child3->R.id.cellAvatar (findViewById(R.id.cellAvatar) finds the child1.cellAvatar again)
```

by using `child.findViewById(R.id.cellAvatar)`, it ensures that you find the correct R.id.cellAvatar for each run of the loop.

Does that make sense?

**Update 2:**

When you call:

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cellevery, lLfD);
```

You are already setting the parent view as the second argument so you don't need to call:

```
lLfD.addView(child);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, I'm sorry but I'm new at android dev and is the first time I use inflater without an adapter, could you explain your answer further?

Comment: findViewById finds the first view with R.id.cellAvatar, on your second loop, findViewById (without child.) finds R.id.cellAvatar of the first loop, same with the third loop and so on.

Comment: So I should inflate outside the loop and then populate the views?

Comment: No, the inflater is designed to work inside loops. findViewById will only find the first view with the R.id that you pass in. Since you are inflating a custom view, the R.id.cellAvatar is found multiple times in your activity so it continually finds the first one. Look at my updated answer and let me know if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I done the modifications as you suggested and still happens the same problem, however following your logic if I change the ID of the field avatar and  cellname to (0) it works perfect, got the idea from this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839998/android-using-inflater-only-first-item-of-the-list-gets-correctly-populated)

Comment: Yes, that's doing the same thing.. by calling child.findViewById, it just does the search from the child view and not the entire view hierarchy of the activity. I also made another comment in my update 2.